# Logic Error - Derived Class not passing variables to parent function

Tags: c++, inheritance

When I run this code, the name and salary variables are never set using the derived class "Programmer", even though it passes the variables through the parent class' constructor as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071466/trouble-with-inheritance-derived-class-not-inheriting-base-class).  No errors are being given, but the name and salary variables just don't seem to get set for some reason.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


class Employee 
{
public:
   Employee();
   Employee(string employee_name, double initial_salary);

   void set_salary(double new_salary);
   double get_salary() const;
   string get_name() const;
private:
   string name;
   double salary;
};


Employee::Employee()
{  
   salary = 0;
}

Employee::Employee(string employee_name, double initial_salary)
{  
   name = employee_name;
   salary = initial_salary;
}

void Employee::set_salary(double new_salary)
{  
   salary = new_salary;
}

double Employee::get_salary() const
{  
   return salary;
}

string Employee::get_name() const
{  
   return name;
}

class Programmer : public Employee {
public:
    Programmer(string name, double salary);
    string get_name();
private:
};

Programmer::Programmer(string pname, double psalary)
{
    Employee(pname, psalary);
}

string Programmer::get_name()
{
    return Employee::get_name();
}

int main() {
    Programmer harry("Hacker, Harry", 10000);
    cout << harry.get_name();
    return 0;
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385280/accessing-base-class-member-variable-from-derived-class-instantiated-from-deriv) wasn't the same as my problem from what I could tell.  Though that one was much more complex.

It seems like a simple logic error, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a member initializer list to initiate base class. With your constructor, you create a tempoarary Employee in the function body.

```
Programmer::Programmer(string pname, double psalary)
  : Employee(pname, psalary)  
{}
```

Comment: Okay, I see the big difference there.  If you don't mind helping out with the understanding, is that difference in structure because it's a constructor?

Comment: Yes, constructors have member intializer lists (: followed by a comma separated list of initializations of base classes and members) to initialize its bases and members before the start of the function body.

Answer (score 0):

```
Programmer::Programmer(string pname, double psalary)
{
    Employee(pname, psalary);
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
Programmer::Programmer(string pname, double psalary) :
   Employee()
   // Base class is initialized using the default constructor.
{
    Employee(pname, psalary);
    // Create a temporary Employee and discard it.
}
```

To pass `name` and `psalary` to initialize the base class, you'll need to use:

```
Programmer::Programmer(string pname, double psalary) :
   Employee(pname, psalary)
   // Base class is initialized using the constructor
   // that takes name and salary as arguments.
{
}
```

Comment: I see, so the compiler defaults (somewhat obviously) to the default constructor unless you use the ":" to indicate the other one?

Comment: @Logan, that is correct. Same thing applies to member variables too.

Comment: Thank you, that information is something I'll make a note of!